# Unable to use Maven BOM in gradle 5 with annotationProcessor configuration

Tags: spring-boot, gradle, annotation-processing, maven-bom

I am trying to use maven BOM with gradle 5.1.1 as mentioned below

```
ext {
  set('spring-boot-dependencies.version', '2.1.2.RELEASE')
}

apply plugin: 'java'

group 'com.acme'
version '1.0.0-SNAPSHOT'

sourceCompatibility = 1.8

repositories {
  mavenCentral()
  jcenter()
}

dependencies {
  // maven bom
  implementation platform("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-dependencies:${project.'spring-boot-dependencies.version'}")

  compileOnly('org.projectlombok:lombok')
  annotationProcessor('org.projectlombok:lombok')
}
```

When I run `./gradlew dependencies --configuration=annotationProcessor` & `./gradlew dependencies --configuration=compileOnly`, I get the following respectively

```
annotationProcessor - Annotation processors and their dependencies for source set 'main'.
\--- org.projectlombok:lombok FAILED
```

```
compileOnly - Compile only dependencies for source set 'main'.
+--- org.projectlombok:lombok FAILED
```

Strangely, IntelliJ resolves `compileOnly` dependencies properly, but not `annotationProcessor`

I am quite confused as to what is going on. Any help is appreciated

[image: intellij gradle view]

Answer (score 20, accepted):

In Gradle, a platform, like regular dependencies, is scoped to a given configuration (and the configurations extending it).

In your example, the BOM is only used in `implementation` and thus will only provide recommendations for that configuration and the ones extending it, like `compileClasspath` or `runtimeClasspath`.

In order to solve your issue, you will need to declare the BOM to all the configurations where you want to benefit from its recommended versions.

You can achieve this by repeating the declaration:

```
compileOnly platform("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-dependencies:${project.'spring-boot-dependencies.version'}")
annotationProcessor platform("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-dependencies:${project.'spring-boot-dependencies.version'}")
```

or you could create a dedicated configuration and make all the configurations requiring constraints extend it:

```
configurations {
    springBom
    compileOnly.extendsFrom(springBom)
    annotationProcessor.extendsFrom(springBom)
    implementation.extendsFrom(springBom)
}

dependencies {
    springBom platform("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-dependencies:${project.'spring-boot-dependencies.version'}")
}
```

Comment: I just tested your solution in `build.gradle`. Can you make the configurations section in your answer to look like this
`springBom compileOnly.extendsFrom(springBom) annotationProcessor.extendsFrom(springBom) implementation.extendsFrom(springBom)`